# Helvetica Neue issues on Windows Chrome

Tags: css, fonts, font-size

We are trying to use Helvetica Neue but it does not render correctly on Windows. In the screenshot you can see that depending on the font-size, some letters have different height than others and letter "D" renders bad in some font sizes.

This image was rendered on Windows and Chrome. On Safari Mac looks ok.

Sample on different font sizes:

[image: Sample on different font sizes]

Do you know why it looks like this and how to fix?

Code:

```css
@font-face {
 font-family: HelveticaNeue;
 src: url('font/HelveticaNeueLight.ttf');
 font-weight:normal;
}

@font-face {
 font-family: HelveticaNeue;
 src: url('font/HelveticaNeueMedium.ttf');
 font-weight:500;
}

@font-face {
 font-family: HelveticaNeue;
 src: url('font/HelveticaNeueBold.ttf');
 font-weight:bold;
}

html, body {
 font-family:HelveticaNeue, 'Arial Narrow';
}


p {
  font-weight:bold;
  margin-top:0;
  margin-bottom:1rem;
  text-align:center;
  display:block;
  line-height:1.5;
}
```

```html
<p style="font-size:14px !important">14px MÅNADSVIS</p>
```

Comment: Without code we can't help you. Please add the relevant code of your css.

Answer (score -1):

You could try playing around with the two properties font-smooth and text-rendering and see if that improves anything.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-smooth

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/text-rendering